# How can a device be mounted on several mount points, while directory listings for the mount points list different files?

Tags: bash, debian, rhel, filesystems, docker

Consider the device called `/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv`. It's mounted on `/var`, `/var/lib/docker/containers`, and `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` and its filesystem is XFS.

If the same filesystem is mounted on several mount points, why isn't `ls` on these directories showing the same files?

From my understanding of mounts, all these mount points should contain the device's filesystem?

`mount`:

```
[root@y96553 PROD:~]# mount | grep /dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv
/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv on /var/lib/docker/containers type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv on /var/lib/docker/overlay2 type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
[root@y96553 PROD:~]# ls /var
adm  cache  chef  crash  db  empty  games  gopher  kerberos  lib  local  lock  log  mail  McAfee  nis  opt  preserve  run  spool  tmp  yp
[root@y96553 PROD:~]# ls /var/lib/docker/containers
56ed3a21afb89c349d6875c7d20b25444ba9ee815e0e824dc170d26607a4927b
[root@y96553 PROD:~]# ls /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
24a49eff8d1f800fed4322175c5fc9484a6de1450c9a0be93cce211f552f25ca  4924094529d96ff12c9056ddab973033490487d7d3d67d233ecb744d46af6dca       713f40d71da92ed84dd9ffeab1120ed67e41129c4b05b3bbfa6591fb2887c0e7  f31491209a27299b5ec1a3eac5124cdfc87d5d560556ef0cedeaac399240f360
29932c5a880ca121835cc8504e6867b1d444b3976d34cff3f811599ffcab0f62  551611ac2f31020b360c58643ac2061147774cc9ba29658d3d3f96957d2b7f3c       8264bb5eca21d3a0d2e22138dd8d9a65bc63e726ad96aaac432b7d43c3dbd60a  f96545439fa89cebe1051b1490b158dfad6454801bb6d8cd0b1f33e28dadeb86
38ae310c1c7c5ae2fcc3a86bda004072957748c1d341341d4eb7b2739857893f  57ebabdc33cb0333945220b77d84fb300ad0953c75b7c07a98b2850df3e95189       backingFsBlockDev                                                 fe05a87de4abb611c9702f43db5f364f5b9f0acc2c9a69a09b770925c799c3a2
3d04967d655cbe8b54170924ef4d7b65cde5dc4106ade1d644f8a29b73b6d84c  613a1567b74a9d15e41afce1acabcb33ea02317b1c4285f8f89a4b3bf9193b4f       e242e54d57d164b8a1ef7dbe5de77bd64d90ac9c73d59c23627a7a8e04afec7b  l
464da1098500d9b5c26fd9b12b1a4ae3125c84d3dad5bb5f29ce6414dc2c64ba  613a1567b74a9d15e41afce1acabcb33ea02317b1c4285f8f89a4b3bf9193b4f-init  f1c8cce1e5edf230bccd0a594841d701ce0f4ca5f71aba1374117f07c67c83fa
```

`lsblk`:

```
[root@y96553 PROD:~]# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   60G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 59.3G  0 part
  ├─systemvg-rootlv   253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  /
  ├─systemvg-swaplv   253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─systemvg-usrlv    253:2    0   10G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─systemvg-homelv   253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─systemvg-optlv    253:4    0    5G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─systemvg-tmplv    253:5    0    5G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─systemvg-kdumplv  253:6    0    2G  0 lvm  /var/crash
  ├─systemvg-varloglv 253:7    0   10G  0 lvm  /var/log
  └─systemvg-varlv    253:8    0    5G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                     8:16   0  500G  0 disk
```

Comment: Take a look at `findmnt` output instead of `mount`. This probably (I believe) will provide a clue for you.

Comment: @DanilaKiver - Thank you! I see that two of the mounts have a path appended to them in brackets, e.g. `/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv[...]`. So, this is a path within the filesystem  (`/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv`) that is mounted at that particular mountpoint? Why doesn't `mount` show this in the output (can it show it)? Furthermore, I didn't knew it was possible to mount a path within a filesystem at a mountpoint, but only a filesystem - can you elaborate? Aren't these extra mounts unnecesary, since I already have `/dev/mapper/systemvg-varlv` on `/var`?